# Re-forking a deleted fork on GitHub

Tags: github, http-status-code-404, fork

A few days ago, I deleted a fork on GitHub.
Now I can't re-fork the same project, when I do it, GitHub show me a 404 error.

When I fork, GitHub redirect me to a page like `"https://github.com/<project_name>-1"` as if the project is still available on my space.

Comment: Have you tried contacting their support? re-forking a repo should work fine. Maybe it has something to do with the issues they had with their file servers in the last days.

Comment: No, I haven't contact the support because I didn't know if this was a common problem. I've deleted the fork when GitHub had his problem with file server. Thanks for the answer, now I ask them ;)

Comment: It's confirmed that were a GitHub problem.
They deleted correctly my fork and now all it's ok.
Thank you

Comment: glad you got this resolved ;)

Comment: If _0xNaN_ helped here, shouldn't that comment be rewritten to an answer, to be accepted and bring some rep?